# Update row in BEFORE DELETE trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-10

In short: I need to update a row in `BEFORE DELETE` trigger and get error:

> tuple to be updated was already modified by an operation triggered by the current command

I know that there is no much sense in updating the row that will be deleted, but...

In my case I have a function to cancel an order. It does some operations including clearing the discount code from the order (so the code can be used again). I want to use the same function in a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger (order deletion is also a kind of cancellation).

Now I have to *manually* call the cancel function and then delete the order. I want to avoid the risk of accidentally deleting an order without cancelling it first, so `BEFORE DELETE` trigger is an obvious choice.

Is there a workaround? Any suggestions?

Why can't I update the row that is going to be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a restriction caused by the implementation that keeps you from doing that. It has to do with the concept of “tuple visibility” in PostgreSQL.

I would add an additional `boolean` parameter `modify_row` that defaults to `TRUE` to the cancel function that determines if the row should be updated or not. Then you can call the function in your trigger with `modify_row => FALSE`.

Comment: I was also thinking about adding a parameter but didn't want to search and change every call of cancel function. I forgot about default parameters - now I only need to change the call from the trigger. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Your description leads me to believe there is considerable additional processing that deleting the row would not accomplish (for example inserting the discount code into a available discount_code table). I would accomplish this by calling the cancel routine before issuing the delete statement then in a delete trigger validate the old.discount_code is available. If not then throw an exception.